# Oracle 11g order by and rownum in nested select does not work with inner join

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-order-by, limit

I want to return two columns where the second one is a username linked through a foreign id. I am worried there might exist such multiple records varying in the state, so I would like to order by a state (custom precedence) and get the first one found.

Here is the working query before the edit.

```
select entry.ID,
    (select username.USERNAME from USER_CREDENTIALS username
     inner join CREDENTIALS cred on username.ID = cred.ID
     where cred.SUBJECT_ID=entry.SUBJECTID
    )
from ENTRY entry
where entry.ID in (1, 2, 5);
```

My ultimate goal is to secure the inner select returns up to one record (no record results in `null` which is fine). So here I use `rownum` with `ORDER BY` a state *custom precedence) with respect to the issue with `rownum` and `ORDER By` in the same query described [here](https://sqlandplsql.com/2017/10/15/rownum-and-order-by-in-oracle/) (source sqlandplsql.com). I ended up with something like this:

```
select entry.ID,
       (select * from
           (select username.USERNAME from USER_CREDENTIALS username
            inner join CREDENTIALS cred on username.ID = cred.ID
            where cred.SUBJECT_ID=entry.SUBJECTID
            order by case when cred.STATE = 'A' then 1 else 2 end
           )
       where rownum=1
       )
from ENTRY entry
where entry.ID in (1, 2, 5);
```

This throws the exception:

> [42000][904] ORA-00904: "ENTRY"."SUBJECTID": invalid identifier

I suspect only such attribute is visible only to the first-level nested select. However, I need to use the `rownum`-`ORDER BY` combo through another select which is not compliant with the `"ENTRY"."SUBJECTID"` visibility.

How to rewrite the queue to get rid of the error and make it  `rownum`-`ORDER BY` safe?

Comment: Showing sample data for SQL questions here is really akin to the saying that "a picture is worth a thousand words."  That being said, can you add sample input data and the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle does not (generally) allow correlation clauses in more than one level of nesting.  Instead, you can use `keep`:

```
select e.ID,
       (select max(uc.USERNAME) keep (dense_rank first order by (case when c.STATE = 'A' then 1 else 2 end))
        from USER_CREDENTIALS uc join
             CREDENTIALS c 
             on uc.ID = c.ID
        where c.SUBJECTID = e.SUBJECTID
       )
from ENTRY e
where e.ID in (1, 2, 5);
```

`keep` is Oracle's fancy syntax for a "first" aggregation function.

Comment: Thanks, it looks promising. However, `[42000][907] ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis` is thrown.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis . . That `ORDER BY` should not have been there.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis . . .  Here is a db<>fiddle showing that the syntax works:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0c9c84094dcafcf6e966fa636db6be44.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reference an identifier that is more than one sub-query removed. In your case, you refer to `ENTRY.SUBJECTID` in a sub-query nested two deep and the identifier cannot be seen. Instead, you need to move the filter to the outer sub-query:

## Option 1

```sql
select e.ID,
       (  select USERNAME
          from   (
            select c.SUBJECT_ID,
                   u.USERNAME
            from   USER_CREDENTIALS u
                   inner join CREDENTIALS c
                   on ( u.ID = c.ID )
            order by case when STATE = 'A' then 1 else 2 end
          ) t
          WHERE t.SUBJECT_ID = e.SUBJECTID
          AND   rownum=1
       ) AS username
from   ENTRY e
where  e.ID in (1, 2, 5);
```

## Option 2

Or by using the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function:

```sql
select e.ID,
       (  select USERNAME
          from   (
            select c.SUBJECT_ID,
                   u.USERNAME,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                     PARTITION BY c.SUBJECT_ID
                     ORDER BY case when STATE = 'A' then 1 else 2 end
                   ) As rn
            from   USER_CREDENTIALS u
                   inner join CREDENTIALS c
                   on ( u.ID = c.ID )
          ) t
          WHERE t.SUBJECT_ID = e.SUBJECTID
          AND   rn=1
       ) AS username
from   ENTRY e
where  e.ID in (1, 2, 5);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE entry ( id, subjectid ) AS
SELECT LEVEL, LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5;

CREATE TABLE credentials ( id, subject_id ) AS
SELECT LEVEL, LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5;

CREATE TABLE user_credentials ( id, username, state ) AS
SELECT LEVEL, 'NameA' || LEVEL, 'A' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 4 UNION ALL
SELECT LEVEL, 'NameB' || LEVEL, 'B' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5;
```

Both output:

> ```
> ID | USERNAME
> -: | :-------
>  1 | NameA1  
>  2 | NameA2  
>  5 | NameB5
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e20a9249c49118edec7251d0f67717b8)*

If you were using Oracle 12, you could use the `FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY` syntax:

```sql
select e.ID,
       (  select u.USERNAME
          from   USER_CREDENTIALS u
                 inner join CREDENTIALS c
                 on ( u.ID = c.ID )
          WHERE t.SUBJECT_ID=e.SUBJECTID
          order by case when STATE = 'A' then 1 else 2 end
          FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
       )
from   ENTRY e
where  e.ID in (1, 2, 5);
```

(Which has the same `EXPLAIN PLAN` as the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic solution).

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=86c53a7059e47efc6037d77a74f0328e)*